# Nightwatch, How to call 'Setup' and 'Teardown' API globally

Tags: api, installation, nightwatch.js, teardown

I am just getting started learning nightwatchjs to test my webapp. I need to call a 'setup' and a 'teardown' script before and after everything else, respectively. These scripts create the necessary conditions in the database for the tests to run (creating test licenses, users, etc), and remove them afterward. I have an API call in my app that triggers these.

In globals.js, you can set `before` and `after` methods that should execute before and after everything else, and also a `beforeEach` and `afterEach` that should execute before and after each test suite, if I'm not mistaken. It seems the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` methods accept as arguments a `browser` object and a `done` callback. The `before` and `after` methods, however, only get the `done` callback.

In a particular test suite, the same four methods can be added, but in this case, the `before` and `after` run before everything and after everything, respectively, and the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` run before and after each individual test in the suite.

Ideally, I would call my `setup` and `teardown` scripts in the global `before` and `after` methods, but those do not get an instance of nightwatch (browser), so I don't know how I'd do that.

I am able to fire off the 'setup' call just fine, in my globals `beforeEach` method. This isn't ideal for me, but it would still work, it would just be a but superfluous (calling it before each test suite rather than just once before everything).

However, I run into issues when I try to call the `teardown` script from my globals `afterEach` method. When I run my test, the output hangs at the end, until I hit `CTRL+C`.

Here is my nightwatch.conf.js:

```
const seleniumServer = require("selenium-server");
const chromedriver = require("chromedriver");


// we use a nightwatch.conf.js file so we can include comments and helper functions
module.exports = {
    "src_folders": [
        "tests",
    ],
    "page_objects_path": './pages',
    "globals_path": "./globals.js",
    "output_folder": "./reports", // reports (test outcome) output by nightwatch
    "custom_commands_path" : "./commands",
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true, // tells nightwatch to start/stop the selenium process
        "server_path": seleniumServer.path,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444, // standard selenium port
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver" : chromedriver.path
        }
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "silent": true,
            "launchUrl": 'http://local.mytestwebsite.com',
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true, // if you want to keep screenshots
                "path": "./screenshots/" // save screenshots here
            },
            "globals": {
                "waitForConditionTimeout": 5000 // sometimes internet is slow so wait.
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": { // use Chrome as the default browser for tests
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        "window-size=1366,768",
                        "--incognito"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my globals.js:

```
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
module.exports = {


    beforeEach: function(browser, done) {
        console.log('Executing the global `beforeEach`');

        browser.url('http://www.vulfpeck.com');
        browser.expect.element('body').to.be.present;
        browser.end();

        // getting the session info
        browser.status(function(result) {
            console.log("Session Info: ", result.value);
            done();
        });
    },


    afterEach: function(browser, done){
        console.log('Executing the global `afterEach`');

        browser.url('http://www.vulfpeck.com');
        browser.expect.element('body').to.be.present;
        browser.end();

        // getting the session info
        browser.status(function(result) {
            console.log("Session Info: ", result.value);
            done();
        });
    },


    before: function(done) {
        console.log('Executing the global `before`');
        console.log('starting the chromedriver');
        chromedriver.start();
        done();
    },


    after: function(done) {
        console.log('Executing the global `after`');
        console.log('stoppin the chromedriver');
        chromedriver.stop();
        done();
    }
};
```

And here is my test suite:

```
module.exports = {
    'Test 1': function(browser){
        browser.url('http://www.google.com');
        browser.expect.element('body').to.be.present;
        browser.end();
    },
    'Test 2': function(browser){
        browser.url('http://www.vulfpeck.com');
        browser.expect.element('body').to.be.present;
        browser.end();
    },
    before: function(browser, done){
        console.log('test before');
        done();
    },
    beforeEach: function(browser, done){
        console.log('test beforeEach');
        done();
    },
    after: function(browser, done){
        console.log('test after');
        done();
    },
    afterEach: function(browser, done){
        console.log('test afterEach');
        done();
    }
};
```

Here is the output.

```
$ nightwatch
Executing the global `before`
starting the chromedriver
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  11772

[Login] Test Suite
======================
Executing the global `beforeEach`
 √ Expected element <body> to be present - element was present in 31ms
Session Info:  { ready: true,
  message: 'Server is running',
  build:
   { revision: '63f7b50',
     time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z',
     version: '3.9.1' },
  os: { arch: 'amd64', name: 'Windows 10', version: '10.0' },
  java: { version: '9' } }
test before

Running:  Test 1
test beforeEach
 √ Expected element <body> to be present - element was present in 30ms
test afterEach

OK. 1 assertions passed. (3.56s)

Running:  Test 2
test beforeEach
 √ Expected element <body> to be present - element was present in 20ms
test afterEach

OK. 1 assertions passed. (2.503s)
test after
Executing the global `afterEach`
Session Info:  { ready: true,
  message: 'Server is running',
  build:
   { revision: '63f7b50',
     time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z',
     version: '3.9.1' },
  os: { arch: 'amd64', name: 'Windows 10', version: '10.0' },
  java: { version: '9' } }
 × Expected element <body> to be present - element was not found  - expected "present" but got: "not present"
    at Object.afterEach (C:\sites\mytestwebsite.com\selenium\globals.js:29:21)
```

So, am I missing something? Why can I not hit a URL in the global afterEach method without it hanging? (I just figured out that if I remove the `browser.end();` from my last test in the suite, my global `afterEach` will work just fine. Why is this?). Is there some other recommended way of hitting a URL before and after running all tests?

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't completely answered my own question, I have come up with an alternate way to call my setup and teardown scripts in the globals `before` and `after` hooks.

For this, I have installed the node libarary `child_process` (by typing `npm install child_process`), which allows me to execute commands on the command line.

In my `globals.js`, I am requiring that library at the top:

`const { exec } = require('child_process');`

And in my `before` and `after` hooks, I am using it like so:

```
exec('php ../run.php api selenium setup', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                // node couldn't execute the command
                console.log("node couldn't execute the command",err);
                done();
                return;
            }

            // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            done();
        });
```

Hope this helps someone.